# Zoom in/out on click in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

How to zoom in map in OpenLayerss 3 on click of button?

I want to zoom in and zoom out the map on custom buttons instead of + and - buttons which are on default map.

I tried with:

```
onclick="map.zoomIn();"
```

But it's not working, though it was working in OpenLayers 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to zoom in if you click on the map the following should work:

```
map.on('click', function() {
    map.getView().setZoom(map.getView().getZoom()+1);    
});
```

Comment: I want to click on button not on map. This button is custom button.

Comment: Thank you. it is working. map.getView().setZoom(map.getView().getZoom()+1);

Comment: This works, but is very rough, not smooth.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a smooth zoom:

```
map.getView().animate({
  zoom: map.getView().getZoom() + 1,
  duration: 250
})
```

Comment: I have legacy openlayers code v.3.2.0 and there is no `.animate`, this code worked:


```javascript

var zoomAnimation = ol.animation.zoom({
   resolution: map.getView().getResolution()
  });
map.beforeRender(zoomAnimation);
map.getView().setResolution(map.getView().getResolution() * 2 );

```

Answer (score 0):

I have legacy openlayers code v.3.2.0 and there is no `.animate`, this code worked:

```js
var zoomAnimation = ol.animation.zoom({
   resolution: map.getView().getResolution()
});

map.beforeRender(zoomAnimation);
map.getView().setResolution(map.getView().getResolution() * 2 );
```