# Adding button zoom to map using OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers, web-mapping, zoom

I am a beginner in web programming using OpenLayers 3.

In my project i want to add a button to zoom in the map by clicking or selecting a part in the map using OpenLayers 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is a duplicate of this: [Zoom in/out on click in OpenLayers 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162967/zoom-on-click-openlayers-3) and it is already answered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19586185/openlayers-adding-custom-button explains how to add a button, this is to be combined with the event.